# Error Python : org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init> WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font

Tags: python, java, pdfbox, tabula

I'm using a Python script that extracts the text content of a PDF file using tabula which works fine on the Local machine (windows). However, On Remote Server (Red Hat) I get a WARNING

```
Got stderr: Aug 08, 2022 2:09:36 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Roman
Aug 08, 2022 2:09:36 PM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font <init>
WARNING: Using fallback font LiberationSans for base font Times-Bold
...
```

This is the python script

```
import tabula
tables = tabula.read_pdf(file_path,pages='all',lattice=True,relative_area=True)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Install the missing fonts on that system `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. The ZapfDingbats font you'll have to buy or get elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I am using redhat linux, what is the syntax for cmd?

Comment: I don't understand the question, you need to open a window for a command shell. https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-terminal-window  If the command I mentioned doesn't work, then find a way to install the fonts arial / helvetica, times, courier (all these in normal, bold, italic and bold+italic), symbol and Zapf Dingbats.